# Request all folders with imap with thunderbird

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap

I configured in the browser application of MS Outlook 365 a bunch of rules to filter emails before receiving them.

As Example:

```
If sender == Hans.Jochen move mail to folder "Hans.Jochen"
```

If I would use this Account with a fresh Thunderbird installation, I would only see new Mails inside "Inbox" and had to click on all folders in which those mails are moved.

So I enabled an Option, which was not `mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new`, but achieves similar behavior (I think so, never tested).

I know want to deactivate this Option, because it takes some time to update all the folders everytime I start Thunderbird.

Any idea what other setting it could be?

Comment: Did you operate on Outlook desktop client? If so, how did you filter you emails? And what does this have to do with email downloading? In order to better solve your problem, please describe your problem in detail, such as providing some steps.

Comment: No I use the "cloud" solution from o365. I configured a list of rules on the web-interface. I try to edit.